# Library generated from `svd2rust` is not as the standard format with modules

Tags: rust, embedded, svd

According to [this](https://github.com/japaric/stm32f30x/tree/master/src) crate all the functions are clearly nested inside modules and each of the folder contains mod.rs file which contains the source code. I use the same `svd` file and used the `svd2rust` tool to generate the crate myself following the same instructions listed [here](https://docs.rs/svd2rust/0.16.1/svd2rust/). Even after following the instructions in exact manner, I did not get the exact format, for example: instead of `stm32f30x/src/gpioa/afrh/mod.rs` I get a path of stm32f30x/src/gpioa/afrh.rs and I dont have an `afrh` directory that contains `mod.rs`.

I am a beginner to rust and please forgive me if I am being stupid. If possible please explain the reason for this and any command that I could used to generate exact order to generate the library same as in [here](https://github.com/japaric/stm32f30x/tree/master/src/gpioa/afrh).

Following is an image of my gpioa directory, there I dont have anymore folders and no `mod.rs` file.

PS: I checked the code and it contains all the functions with the modules. I just need to separate these modules as it has done in the original library

[image: this is my directory]

Comment: Why do you want the old format? This code should compile as well.

Comment: @Cerberus What do you mean by the old format?

Comment: In other words, why do you want multiple folders with `mod.rs` in each and not multiple files?

Comment: @Cerberus Hm. I know this is strange. But to be honest, when I build the library and inspect it with `objdump` with -d flag the older library clearly shows me all the functions and the instructions associated with those functions. However, for my own version it only has less number of functions when compared to the original. I was thinking that the reason was due to my version did not contain separate modules. My actual requirement is to get a dump of the compiled library as similar to the original library so that it contains all the functions and their instructions clearly.